# #Error Handling- Propagating errors to calling function.

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, async-await

Im new to javascript programming and i am required to make a web app. Node.js will be used as the js runtime environment. In order to minimize the amount of time needed for debugging as the app develops I would like to implement a robust error handling scheme. However, due to my limited background I am not sure if what I am implementing is best practise or if it is even adequate. So any feedback will be accepted.

The function is asynchronous and will use catch to detect if any errors occurred while operating. A try-catch statement will be used to catch any errors. This was done in order to allow for individual error identification from the functions. My aim is to propagate the errors up to the calling function that will handle it in the highest level catch statement (in my case where it is logged *this will change eventually). Any feedback?

```js
create: async function(req, res) {
  let data = JSON.parse(req.body.data);
  let result;
  let request_body;
  let sub_networks_lora;
  try {
    request_body = sub_network_api_request_data(data, 1);
    result = await lora_app_server.create_applications(request_body)
      .catch(err => {
        //Error updating application on lora app server
        throw err;
      });
    await db_sub_networks.create_sub_network(result.data.id, data.sub_network_name, data.network_id)
      .catch(err => {
        throw err;
        //Error creating sub network in database 
      });
    sub_networks_lora = await get_sub_networks()
      .catch(err => {
        throw err;
        //Error getting networks from lora app server
      })
    sub_networks_lora = JSON.stringify(sub_networks_lora);
    res.status(200).send({
      sub_networks_lora
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  } finally {}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: What is the expected result if more than one `Promise` object within `try` is rejected?

Comment: @guest271314 the throw will prevent any of the other async functions from running. Hence only one of the functions can throw an error.

Comment: The code at the question returns expected result?

Comment: @guest271314 from the errors I throwed it did. I just wanted some suggestions to make it 'better' or more standard

Comment: @nicholasmitchell There is no objective "better". "standard" is also subjective.

Comment: @nicholasmitchell As noted at the current answer to avoid `Uncaught (in promise)` within `try..catch` each `Promise` can be passed to `Promise.all()`, and using `.map()` each error, if any, handled individually, resulting in both resolved and rejected `Promise` objects capable of being handled at chained `.then()` and further `throw`n to a chained `.catch()`, if that is the manner in which errors are to be handled. The specific approach to handling errors is the choice of the author of the code.

Answer (score 1):

`try...catch` will only handle one error, the remainder, if any, will be uncaught errors.

One approach would be to use `Promise.all()` and `Array.prototype.map()` within the `async` function, `throw` errors from within `.then()` chained to `create()` to `.catch()` if necessary.

```js
async function create() {
  let results = {resolved:[],rejected:[]};
  let a = new Promise(resolve=>setTimeout(resolve,2000,1));
  let b = Promise.reject(2);
  let c = Promise.reject(3);
  await Promise.all(
    Object.entries({a,b,c})
   .map(([k,p])=>
    // `resolve` or `reject` an object having key
    // set to variable declaration; e.g., `a`, `b`, `c`
    // so we know which `Promise` is resolved or rejected
    p.then(d=>results.resolved.push({[k]:d}))
    .catch(e=>results.rejected.push({[k]:e}))
   )
  );
  return results;
}

create()
.then(({resolved,rejected})=>{
  console.log({resolved}); 
  // `throw` errors to `.catch()` if necessary, here
  if (rejected.length) {
    throw new Error(
    JSON.stringify(rejected))
  }
})
.catch(e=>console.error({caught:e}));
```